# WooCommerce WP_Query using tax_query returns no results (0 = 1)

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy

I am trying to get specific Products from WooCommerce baseed on a Product Attribute (taxonomy).

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                 array(
                       'taxonomy'         => 'pa_range-kwh',
                       'terms'            => 'k2',
                       'field'            => 'slug',
                       'operator'         => 'IN',
                       'include_children' => true,
                        ),
            
            ),
    
    
        );
```

From an SQL point of view
I can see that:

`` SELECT * FROM `wp_terms` WHERE term_id = 891 ``

returns

[image: wp_terms]

`` SELECT * FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` where term_id = 891 ``

returns
[image]

`` SELECT * FROM `wp_term_relationships` where term_taxonomy_id = 891 ``

returns

[image: wp_term_relationships]

Although there is at least one product where the taxonomy is added, I keep on receiving 0 results due to the inner query returning (0 = 1), meaning it can't find any product with this taxonomy attributed.

Any ideas on what could I do to overcome this?

P.S. the complete function

```
$GLOBALS['SERVER_SIDE_EQUATIONS']['get_products'] = function(){

    $products = '';

 
    
    $argsAlt = array(
            'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true,
            'range-kwh' => 'k2',
            'pa_range-kwh' => 'k2',
            'lazy_load_term_meta' => false,
            'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy'         => 'pa_range-kwh',
                'terms'            => array('k2'),
                'field'            => 'slug',
                'operator'         => 'IN',
                'include_children' => true,
            ),
            
),//end tax_array
    
    
        );

        $queryAlt = new WP_Query( $argsAlt );



        if($queryAlt->have_posts()){
            $products .='yes ';
            $products .= $custom_posts->found_posts. "<br />";          
            $_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
            foreach($queryAlt->posts as $post){
                $product_obj = $_pf->get_product($post->ID);
                $products .= $product_obj->get_title();
            } //end foreach
        }else{
            $products .= '<br />There are no products that satisfy the search criteria.';
        }//end if       
 
    return $products;
};
```

Comment: My problem is similar to this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371797/woocommerce-wp-query-using-tax-query-returns-no-results-0-1

Comment: As you're proficient with MySQL, one way to debug this would be to use the Wordpress query log, or for example the Query Monitor plugin to find the SQL generated by WP_Query and then take it apart to see why it's returning 0 rows and update the query args accordingly

Comment: Where are you using the code, what page and where on that page, is it in a hook? And you can try adding `'suppress_filters' => true` to your query args and see if that helps (i.e. whether the `0 = 1` still happening). If suppressing filters helps, i.e. the issue doesn't persist, then maybe a plugin or code is filtering your query.

Comment: thanks to both for the input. 
I was about to add some extra info. 

I am running this query through the server side scripts of CFF plugin. I did use 'suppress_filters' already but no luck

In a demo page, I manage to get the result after all, not using at all the tax_query but declaring a value pair "pa_range-kwh" => 'k2' in the argument list and adding 'lazy_load_term_meta' => false. Strangely it works.

I am debugging via print_r on the WP_Query object, but I don't see the taxonomy query, as I only get the result (0 = 1). 
Did not try yet with the query log. is my next step :)

Comment: is just very strange, as if the taxonomy is ignored because of the server side script, or the plugin itself

Comment: What's the CFF plugin? Can you show all the query args that you've tried? And more of your code, e.g. the part that calls `new WP_Query`.

Comment: Sure! I will amend my question to include the query. CFF is plugin with forms, which has an extra functionality of [server side scripts](https://cff.dwbooster.com/blog/2019/11/05/case-of-use-filtering-products)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with the plugin, but for (manual) debugging purposes, try [these](https://pastebin.com/7GuyLUzN) and share the output.

Comment: thanks @SallyCJ! very kind of you :) will get back to you asap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111056/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-kernel52).

Answer (score 0):

Plugin's company proposed a solution to go with the wpdb object and write manually the queries...
Kudos to [@Sally CJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj). You were right in you theory, as the taxonomies are not yet known (or registered) when the script is executed.
I will go with this approach for now, as time is limited, but will try to get back if I find a solution to the initial problem.

Comment: @Sally CJ gets the credit